# PRISM + Silverlight: Module and View Discovery

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism

We are using PRISM to divide a large application up into modules, each of which will represent a department in our company:

```
HumanResources
Accounting
InformationSystems
(...)
```

Each Module will have several views.  For example, `Accounting.Module` might have:

```
BusinessIntelligenceView(/Model)
ReportingView(/Model)
```

What I would like to have happen would be for the application to load the modules (which I will manually enter into the `ModuleCatalog`).  Then, I would like the `ShellView` to automatically display a list of available views, which the user can can use to select a view to inject into the main region.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, I don't think it's built-in within prism, but this is definitely possible :)

A few tips for you...  Please be kind, I didn't use an IDE to write any line of code :)

First, you could create a view (and a view model) to display the list of available views.  Those "available views" could be represented by a class defining the view informations.

Something like :

```
public interface IAvailableView
{
    string ViewName { get; }
    string ModuleName { get; }  
}
```

Second, to be able to display all the available views, your modules needs to be loaded "When available" in your catalog. They will then be triggered at the initialization of your application.

In your modules, you should now register your views under a specific name and you could register all available views exposed by it in a dependency container.

```
public virtual void Initialize()
{  
    RegisterView<IView, AnyView>("AnyView");
    Register<IAvailableView>(new AvailableView("AnyView", "MyModuleName"));
}
```

Once all your modules are loaded, your view model control should be able to resolve all those IAvailableViews.

Now, all you need to do is to bind those available views to a control and Register the correspoding view in the RegionManager once the user click on a item...

```
var view = GetInstance<IView>(selectedAvailableView.ViewName);
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("whateverRegion", () => view);
```

Hope it helps :)